# Windows explorer integration like tortoisesvn

Tags: c#, windows-shell

My company uses a flavour of GIT for moving source code from your local system to the repository at the desired location (which later deploys and stuff , its a server basically) and the support for that tool is BAD. It uses the commandline and its very tedious to use it . I want to build somthing similar to tortoiseSVN / tortoiseGIT for this purpose and i am looking for a starting point.

How would i get the overlay icons in the folder ? 
How would i be able to do windows explorer integration in the "right" way ?

I'm going to use .Net C# to build this tool.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Cheers.

Comment: If only tortoisegit was open source... [Oh wait](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/source/checkout)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [Shell Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)!  There is [a lot to learn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), though.  [Part IX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) of the complete idiot's guide to shell extensions series explains how to deal with icons.

In general writing IE and Shell extensions in C# [isn't supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx).  Of course, newer versions of the runtime do allow you more flexibility in the area of SxS support.  But you're on your own in terms of writing the COM interop and you need to think very carefully about how this will effect other apps that do things like use the file-open dialog.